# Keyboard spacebar hiccup when using Skype

Tags: windows-7, keyboard, skype

I'm using Windows 7 x64 in an AD environment. I've downloaded the most recent version of Skype. However, when I start up the program my spacebar does not work as smooth anymore as it was before the start-up of Skype.

Is there some hidden feature messing with my keyboard or what am I missing?

Any things I could try, except removing Skype? I need Skype to communicate with several people on a daily basis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Still no clue what caused this problem. I've removed Skype, did a reboot and installed a fresh Skype version again.

The problem did not occur anymore, issue resolved (without satisfying answer).

Note:
*I did write this answer down as it might cause the same trouble for anyone else, rather than removing the question.*